# Kivy GUI label text doesn't update itself

Tags: python-3.x, gui, kivy

Возникла проблема, не обновляется текст на экране приложения. Реализовано что-то вроде обратного отсчета, но графический интерфейс не отображает изменений.

Использовал StringProperty, пробовал через self.ids...

Содержание питоновского файла:

```
# encoding:utf-8
# memorizer main file

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


import random


# count = 10
count = 3

class MemoScreen(Screen):

    scr = BooleanProperty(False)
    time_var = StringProperty('Initial')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def number(self):
        return random.randint(100000, 999999)

    def time_left(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global count
        self.time_var = str(count)
        print('time_var: {}'.format(self.time_var))
        if count:
            count -= 1
        else:
            self.time_var = 'Time is over!'
            Clock.unschedule(self.time_left)
            print('time_var: {}'.format(self.time_var))
        # return None


class CheckScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MemorizerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Memorizer'
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MemoScreen(name='MemoScr'))
        sm.add_widget(CheckScreen(name='CheckScr'))
        memo = MemoScreen()
        check = CheckScreen()
        Clock.schedule_interval(memo.time_left, 1.0)
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MemorizerApp().run()
```

Содержание файла .kv

```
# :kivy 1.0.9

<MemoScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            font_size: 70
            size_hint_y: 30
            center_x: root.width / 2
            text: "Memorize this number:"

        Label:
            id: number
            font_size: 100
            size_hint_y: 40
            center_x: root.width / 2
            text: str(root.number())

        Label:
            id: time_left
            font_size: 70
            size_hint_y: 30
            center_x: root.width / 2
            # text: root.time_left()
            text: str(root.time_var)

        # Button:
        #     id: button1
        #     text: 'Go to CheckScreen'
        #     on_press:
        #         root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        #         root.manager.current = 'CheckScr'

<CheckScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: check
            font_size: 70
            size_hint_y: 30
            center_x: root.width / 2
            text: 'Input memorized number!'

        Label:
            id: input_field
            font_size: 100
            size_hint_y: 30

        Label:
            id: time_left_to_fill
            font_size: 70
            size_hint_y: 20
            center_x: root.width / 2

        Button:
            id: btn_submit
            size_hint_y: 20
            center_x: root.width / 2

        Button:
            id: button2
            text: 'Go to CheckScreen'
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                root.manager.current = 'MemoScr'
```

Система Mac OS X Mojave, Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin, Kivy 1.10.1

Заранее благодарен за помощь любого рода.

Comment: Пересмотрел решение. Отказался от kv-файла, реализовал все через код на питоне, используя label.text

Comment: можно еще через self.ids.название_айди.text в классе обращаться.